# Obtener dato e insertar

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

quizas lo que pregunte es muy basico, pero me estoy enredando en esto: tengo una lista de productos Ejm

[image: Aqui va una imagen de referecia, codigo, producto, secuencia, frecuencia]

Lo que necesito es saber si dicho producto existe en mi BDD y sino poder ingresarlo, me diran eso es facil, pero mi manera de insertar es la siguiente, para poder crear el codigo guardo la frecuencia+secuencia.

Por eso consulto a la base para ver si el codigo existe POR EJM 0021 al 0029, en este caso existen 2 datos que son el 0021 y el 0022, pero sino existe necesito poder ingresar el 0023, 0024, 0025 de manera correlativa.

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde pregunto cuando datos ingresados existen pertenecientes a la frecuencia y secuencia

```
$nCod=Productos::where('frecuencia','=',$frecuencia)
            ->where('secuencia', '=', $secuencia)
            ->count();

if($nCod<10){
           $buscar=Productos::where('frecuencia','=',$frecuencia)
            ->where('secuencia', '=', $secuencia)
               ->get();

        }else{
            echo "Error, no se puede ingresar.";
        }
```

Como puedo hacer el ciclo para saber si existe el codigo, sino ingresarlo de manera consecutiva?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas Laravel así que te recomiendo el método `firstorcreate()` que primero buscará una coincidencia con algún registro, si no encuentra coincidencia entonces procederá a hacer una nueva alta

**EJEMPLO**

```
$data = ModelName::firstOrCreate([
    'email' => 'mail@mail.com'
], [
    'comunidad' => 'SO en español',
    'usuarios' => 'muchisimos',
    'calidad' => 'toda la del mundo' 
]);
```

En el ejemplo que te muestro, busca la coincidencia por el email, si no lo encuentra entonces da de alta el registro `comunidad => SO en español`

Comment: aunque no es el unico dato que inserto, inserto como 6 datos mas, igual me sirve ocupar este metodo? Lo consulto, porque no es mucho mi conocimiento en laravel, y como recién estoy consultando si existe el codigo que voy a insertar, dando la frecuencia+secuencia+ un correlativo

Comment: Si @Karli se puede pero deja que pueda y mejoro el ejemplo